# preg_replace whitespace also breaks my special characters

Tags: preg-replace, special-characters, whitespace, line-breaks

I have a string that contains a lot of whitespaces and line breaks that I would like to clean up, so I use:

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str));
```

However, when I echo out $str I notice that special characters like " à " turn into �.

When i remove the preg_replace the � becomes " à " again, but my string is full of whitespaces and linebreaks.

I tried Google (ofc) but not a whole lot of people seem to experience this problem :)

My knowledge of PHP is intermediate, so I (still) kinda lack the insight of where this problem might occur :)

Comment: Your problem may be a result of a bad encoding. Can you tell me what encoding (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, etc.) you are using?

Comment: I'm using UTF-8, but i'm not sure about all my data. I receive the contents of $str trough cURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this could help as there could be a problem with the charset

```
$text = utf8_decode($text);
$text = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text));
$text = utf8_encode($text);
```

are you getting utf-8 input?

Comment: This works, thank you! But does this mean my input is not in the correct charset? I mean, this is a workaround right? Do i need to change my input data ($str) or something on my end? The receive the content of $str trough CURL from another website.

Comment: no most webpages either use utf-8 or  ISO-8859-1 as charset .. (see the header) and utf-8 is (afaik) a multibyte-encoding and therefore is handled differently in php .. I once had a issue with that when using a database ;D .. great that i could help you ;D

Comment: i'm not quite sur (never used this one) but maybe you could also work with [link](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-ereg-replace.php) to replace ;D

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem. preg_replace WILL break a UTF-8 string if it has, among MANY others, one of the following characters (just mentioning some of the more usual cases here):

```
(U+00E0) : à Latin small letter a with grave
(U+0160) : Š Latin capital letter s with caron
(U+03A0) : Π Greek capital letter pi
(U+0420) : Р Cyrillic capital letter er
```

The answer is to use the UTF-8 pattern modifier. There's one catch: UTF-8 can have whitespace characters not caught by `\s`. So you must add `\p{Z}` to your pattern, this matches all whitespace. So use:

```
$str = preg_replace( '/[\p{Z}\s]+/u', ' ', $str );
```

Comment: It still breaks my string, but you give me a hope of understanding the problem